# Question about people in Google street view

Tags: google-workspace

I just use the service recently, and notice that there seems to be no people in the images of street view. Are Google do something to filter people out? (maybe because I have not used it much, or it's that their privacy policy? )

Comment: @phunehehe: I read the policy, it means they still can capture blurring image of people, right? But I can't find any people in their images.

Comment: after rechecking, I saw 1 person. It seems they choose where & when to take pictures very carefully.

Comment: You should have commented on my answer, so that I get notified when you do. Anyway that's true, they have to show respect to privacy.

Comment: Sorry, but I just don't have that priviledge yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's a privacy issue, read more from [Google's policy](http://www.google.com/press/streetview/privacy/).

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of people in Street View images, however Google will honor requests to blur and/or remove images.